# Google Chrome strange gap between div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When I simply put some `<div>` into `<html>`, and turned "Emulated Devices" mode on. Some strange gap showed up between `<div>`. It look like the following:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
li {
  height: 360px;
  background: #000;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 360px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

This problem only occured in Google Chrome "Emulated Devices". How can I fix it?

Comment: May it because of -webkit-margin-before: 0px;-webkit-margin-after: 0px; try this if not please using developer tool change value(for example  -webkit-margin-before: -1px;-webkit-margin-after: 0px; ) and see this might help you.

Comment: yep, fixed it by setting -webkit-margin-before: -2px, but it seems to be a css hack, I wonder why this happened, maybe it's a bug of webkit?

Comment: you can also add the same background on the body element

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is caused by the space between the previous `</div>` and the next `<div>`. Remove all spacing or use a comment between them in the HTML.

There is a similar problem with using inline-block and 50% within a block div at 100%.